# Generating the sequence 111122222333334

Tags: r

I would like to generate the sequence 111122222333334 with either the rep() or seq() function (or any other function), without using c(). I have attempted the following:

```
rep(1:4,rep(4:5,length=4))
```

but it doesn't return my desired outcome. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The obvious question is why don't you want to use `c()` ?

Comment: maybe the homework assignment meant to specify only that you couldn't just use brute force `c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,...)`, not that `c()` was completely disallowed  ? (I think this is the same as @www's comment below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is `rep` with `times`

> times - an integer-valued vector giving the (non-negative) number of times to repeat each element if of length length(x), or to repeat the whole vector if of length 1. Negative or NA values are an error. A double vector is accepted, other inputs being coerced to an integer or double vector.

```
rep(1:4, c(4, 5, 5, 1))
```

---

Or using `seq`

```
rep(1:4, rbind(seq(4, length.out=2, by = 1), seq(5, length.out = 2, by = -4)))
```

Or keep it in a `list` and `unlist`

```
rep(1:4, unlist(list(seq(4, length.out=2, by = 1),
                     seq(5, length.out = 2, by = -4))))
```

or with `Map`

```
rep(1:4, unlist(Map(seq, 4:5, length.out = 2, by = list(1, -4))))
```

Comment: I want to generate this sequence WITHOUT using c()

Comment: @S.P. Which are the functions that cannot be used

Comment: c() is the function that can't be used.

Comment: If this is a homework question, I feel like without using `c` means you cannot do `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, ...)` because it is not practical in the real world. However, akrun's first solution using `rep` and specify a vector `times` should be useful and efficient, while the other ones are overly complicated and probably not very useful in the real world. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Just for obfuscation's sake:

```
rep(1:4,times=head(tail(rep(4:6,each=2),-1),-1))[1:15]
```

Someone should make this into a code golf problem!

The `rep(1:4,times=...)` part is fairly straightforward.

```
head(         ## take all *but* the first element
     tail(    ## take all *but* the last element
          rep(4:6,each=2),  {4,4,5,5,6,6}
       -1),
    -1)
   )[1:15]  ## take the first fifteen elements
```

Or *slightly* more sensibly

```
rep(1:4,times=rep(4:6,each=2)[2:5])[1:15]
```

A more challenging version would say "the character 'c' cannot occur in your answer (which would rule out `each=` as well)